# Is there any Intent filter which can be trigger whenever some text is copied in clipboard in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, clipboard, intentfilter

I need to perform some action in my activity whenever text has been copied in clipboard (My application is in background).Is there any intent filter which can invoke my activity or inform my app that some thing has been copied in clipboard.

Comment: You can use clipboard for this. for reference you can [try this](https://github.com/twaddington/Android-Clipboard-Monitor).

Answer (score 0):

You can create intent filter for your activity, but android provides ClipBoardManager system service which you can exploit.